# HTML elements to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

This feels a mess and I wish It could be neater.

I have a variable number of html elements:

```
<input class="form-control" required="true" name="Spanish" type="text" value="blah blah" id="lang_1">

<input class="form-control" required="true" name="French" type="text" value="hey hey hey" id="lang_2">
```

I want to save these, so I do this:

```
 function saveTranslations() {
   var htmlRows = $("[id^=lang]");
   var rowCount = htmlRows.size();
   for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
     ARRAY_LANGUAGE_ID[i] = htmlRows[i].id;
     ARRAY_DESCRIPTION[i] = htmlRows[i].value;
   }
 }
```

Then I have this my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PATCH',
  url: 'products/' + id,
  data: {
    languageIDs: ARRAY_LANGUAGE_ID,
    descriptiond: ARRAY_DESCRIPTION
  }
});
```

Feels pretty bad, how else can I do this?

Mick

This is almost there:

```
var translations = $("[id^=lang]").serializeArray()
```

Comment: "Feels bad" isn't really an appropriate problem for Stack Overflow, especially if the code shown works as is. Perhaps this question would be better placed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#save').on('click', function() {
    var htmlRows = $('input[id^="lang"]'),
        ARRAY_LANGUAGE_ID = [],
        ARRAY_DESCRIPTION = [];

    $.each(htmlRows, function() {
      ARRAY_LANGUAGE_ID.push($(this).attr('id'));
      ARRAY_DESCRIPTION.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    // AJAX stuff
    console.log(ARRAY_LANGUAGE_ID,
               ARRAY_DESCRIPTION);

  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    lang_1: <input class="form-control" required="true" name="Spanish" type="text" value="blah blah" id="lang_1"><br>
    lang_2: <input class="form-control" required="true" name="French" type="text" value="hey hey hey" id="lang_2"><br><br>
    
    <button id="save">save</button>
  </body>
</html>
```